# load webviews in scrollview fastly in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I am having 20 htmls and i am loading it in the webview.
But, i am creating 3 webviews placing on scrollview and reusing those webviews until the html count finishes.
I am loading html content in

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

and while scrolling the webviews are loading slowly.i want to load those webviews fastly .how to do it.can anyone help me .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to download and cache all the pages before displaying.

See this answer for downloading HTML web pages and writing them locally.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/5607132/300972

Create an array with references to these pages, then load them into the appropriate `UIWebView`'s in `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`.

Update:

Using the link above, it would look something like this. Please note, I have not tested this.

```
// NSArray *urls;
// NSMutableArray *filePaths;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    urls = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://www.url1.com", @"http://www.url2.com", @"http://www.url3.com", nil];

    for (int i=0; i<[urls count]; i++)
    {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.html", [paths objectAtIndex:0], [urls objectAtIndex:i]];   

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urls objectAtIndex:i]];
        NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    }
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{
    // Do some calculation to find index of webpage, this depends on
    // the size of the scrollview and the size of the webview.
    int index = ...;

    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.html", [paths objectAtIndex:0], [urls objectAtIndex:i]];   
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]]];      
}
```

Comment: HOw to create cache and do the things .If is there any sample please tell me