# Downloading a file with Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, ipad, download

I am new to Xcode, attempting to build my first iPad app. I need to write some code to download a file from the internet and save it to the hard drive on the iPad. I have found numerous suggestions on how to save images, or get text files then write them to the hard drive, or viewing .pdf's, but that's not what I'm looking for. I need code that will download any file once the correct URL is put in, and place it in a folder of my choosing. Anyone know how to do that? I would be greatly appreciative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"url to file";
NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Blatantly stolen from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606915/ios-download-and-save-html-file).

BTW your subject shouldn't contain the word 'Xcode' as that is the IDE used to develop the App; it doesn't tell anyone anything about the App environment itself.

Comment: It looks as though the question you took it from utilized a "write" method, am I mistaken? I am unsure if this would work with things that can't be opened as a text file, such as .pdf's or power point files. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @MarcelMarino I don't see why it wouldn't work with binary files as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got it to work. I wish my rep was a bit higher so I could vote you up. If anyone else sees this, I'd appreciating you giving trojanfoe the kudos they deserve.

Comment: @MarcelMarino You should be able to mark it as answered though?

Comment: Done. Sorry, as you can tell, I'm a bit new.