# iOS dataWithContentsOfURL - what's happening behind the scenes

Tags: ios

I've got some simple code (copy and pasted from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606915/ios-download-and-save-html-file)) that loads a KLM (XML based) file into iOS's documents directory. I then display the loaded data on a map.

I realise that this is not a good way of downloading and saving the file - NSUrlConnection seems to be recommended so that the loading can be managed. But I'm new to all this and I'd like to understand what is happening in this case first.

Here's the code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [paths objectAtIndex:0],@"index.kml"];

// Download and write to file
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.co.uk/kml-resource..."];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
[urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

NSURL *fileurl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
kmlParser = [[KMLParser alloc] initWithURL:fileurl];
.....
```

My questions are:

1. What happens while dataWithContentsOfURL is connecting/downloading - does the application just freeze and become unresponsive?
2. If I run my program in aeroplane mode the second time, it still seems to work. When does it decide it's OK to skip the download and writeToFile?
3. Does anyone know if it uses any caching between dataWithContentsOfURL and the server? ie. can I be sure that if I get a response, it is fresh data and hasn't just been sitting in safari/iOS's cache.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. dataWithContentsOfURL is blocking method, so yeah, you shouldn't run that on main thread.
2. probably has internal timeout, but that is private... maybe 60 sec.
3. documentation doesn't say anything about caching, so I assume it doesn't cache at all.

Comment: Thanks @Ivor, for point 2) it just works instantly in aeroplane mode so it's not a timeout test. I'd love to know what it actually does. Also for point 3, if anyone knows for sure I'd be very grateful!

Comment: Jamie, Apple discourages using this method anyway, so I really doubt that you will find any useful (reliable) info with actual source code. I see that you realise already that NSUrlConnection is way to go. If you really want to understand underlying mechanisms, you can always disassemble framework code. For 3., maybe best you can do is set up network configuration where you can sniff traffic and determine what code does.