# Embed a UIwebView in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want embed a `UIWebView` in a UITableViewCell. But there are some problems :

1, I setup the cell's database in method:

```
    (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView 
    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdenWebViewIntro 
    forIndexPath:indexPath];

    PlayListModel * model = [PlayListModel new];
    cell.model = model;
    return cell;

    }
```

And IN the Cell , i setup the webView and send url request in `setModel` Method:

```
- (void)setModel:(PlayListModel *)model{
    _model = model;

    NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://temp url"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10];

    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

It's a quite normal way to config the cell. but when the tableView scroll down and scrolling back to the webViewCell, the system called `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` again, so the webView will send url request again and again. So it's there a way to cache the HTML content of webView. and if the user did not pop out the current view controller I will reuse the HTML for the webView but no to send request multi times.

p.s I already set a cache policy when creating an NSURLRequest, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's expected. TableView will call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method on scrolling.

What you can do is you download the `HTML` content of that `URL` and store it. So, when the cell gets reload you can check that if you have `HTML` content of that `URL` then load it from stored variable or database.

For downloading file, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5607132/4715546).

Comment: exactly ,  do you have any method to download the HTML content?

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to download HTML content by javascript.

```
// DidFinishLoad
-(void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation
{
    NSString *getHTMLJSCode = @"document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML";
    [wkWebView evaluateJavaScript:getHTMLJSCode completionHandler:^(id _Nullable content, NSError * _Nullable error)
     {
         if (error) {
             NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
             return;
         }

         NSLog(@"Content: %@",content);
         self.HTMLSourceCode = content; // cache 
     }];
}
```

You can load request on first loading then cache it.

```
if (HTMLSourceCode) {
    // To load cached webpage.
    [wkWebView loadHTMLString:HTMLSourceCode baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_urlString]];
}
else {
    //...
    [wkWebView loadWithURLRequest:request]
}
```